# How to filter properties of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects:

```
const ObjArray= [{
            "id": "90e17e10-8f19-4580-98a8-ad05f4ecd988",
            "name": "john",
            "description": "worker",
            "place": "f.1.1",
            ...
},
{
            "id": "90e17e10-8eqw-4sdagfr4ecd9fsdfs",
            "name": "joe",
            "description": "dev",
            "stepType": "d.2.1",
            ...
}
];
```

I want to filter the array of objects above to return only specific properties from the objects.

Let's say I want to return only the id and the name of every object in a new array that would look like this:

```
[{
  "id": "90e17e10-8f19-4580-98a8-ad05f4ecd988",
  "name": "john"},
 {
  "id": "90e17e10-8eqw-4sdagfr4ecd9fsdfs",
  "name": "joe" }
```

I searched about that but I couldn't find out how to get it the way I want.

Comment: *"thanks in advance"*: excuse me, but you are supposed to research and try first. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ It is not enough to say *"I searched but could not find"*, since StackOverflow has many similar questions and answers for them.

Comment: Have you try anything ?

Comment: Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: i tried  map(a => a.id) but it apears that it is only works on single property and return all the ids in one object

Comment: try map(a=>({id:a.id, name: a.name})) then

Comment: @trincot so you assumed that i came directly here and asked. thanks anyway

Comment: @AmmarArran, I don't assume anything. But questions should *demonstrate* what you have tried and where you got stuck. Anyway, the question has two parts: how to create a new array from an existing one, and how to create a new object from an existing one. Both questions have been covered extensively on StackOverflow (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664997/object-array-clone-with-subset-of-properties and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
ObjArray= [{
            "id": "90e17e10-8f19-4580-98a8-ad05f4ecd988",
            "name": "john",
            "description": "worker",
            "place": "f.1.1"  },
{
            "id": "90e17e10-8eqw-4sdagfr4ecd9fsdfs",
            "name": "joe",
            "description": "dev",
            "stepType": "d.2.1",}
];

console.log(ObjArray.map(o => ({'id': o['id'], 'name': o['name']})));
```

If you prefer `object destructuring`:

```js
ObjArray= [{
            "id": "90e17e10-8f19-4580-98a8-ad05f4ecd988",
            "name": "john",
            "description": "worker",
            "place": "f.1.1"  },
{
            "id": "90e17e10-8eqw-4sdagfr4ecd9fsdfs",
            "name": "joe",
            "description": "dev",
            "stepType": "d.2.1",}
];

console.log(ObjArray.map(({id, name}) => ({id, name})));
```

Comment: i worked as i wanted i appriciate it