# Get object with a subset of properties of another object

Tags: javascript

I am aware of [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties) however I am interested in only plain javascript solutions (with no external libs like lodash).

What would be **the cleanest way** (including all ES6 goodness and beyond - like object rest & spread etc.) to get an object with a subset of props from another object in javascript?

Lets say I want to pick `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` from `source` object.
I currently have two solutions, I like neither of them:

1.

```
const result = {
  foo: source.foo,
  bar: source.bar,
  baz: source.baz
};
```

2.

```
const { foo, bar, baz } = source;
const target = { foo, bar, baz };
```

The second one is shorter but it pollutes current execution scope with some variables and the list of them has to be written twice anyway.

PS. I am also not interested in augmenting `Object.prototype` with some helper method or calling some custom function to achieve this.

Comment: What is issue with first approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an IIFE with a destruction.

```js
const source = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 },
      target = (({ foo, bar, baz }) => ({ foo, bar, baz }))(source);

console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got an object that contains many properties you need, and and a small amount you don't, you can use the [object rest syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread):

```js
const source = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3, whatever: 4 };

const { whatever, ...target } = source;

console.log(target);
```

**Note** - Object rest is a a Stage 3 proposal for ECMAScript, and a transpiler (babel with the [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment

```js
const source = {foo: 1, bar:2, baz:3, abc: 4, def: 5};

const result = {};

({foo:result.foo, bar:result.bar, baz:result.baz} = source);

console.log(result);
```

Alternatively you can set property names as elements of an array, use `for..of` loop with destructuring assignment to set properties, values of `target`

```js
const source = {foo: 1, bar:2, baz:3, abc:4, def: 5};

const result = {};

for (let prop of ["foo", "bar", "baz"]) ({[prop]:result[prop]} = source);

console.log(result);
```