# Share same model between front-end and server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model, frontend

Simple question but I would like to know how to do this effectively. Very prone to attract negative votes.

I have a model which I want to share between front-end and back-end. For front-end manually I want to add few attributes. These attributes are not required for back end.

```
export class ModelA {
id: string;
name: string;
value: number;
}
```

above is sufficient for server (back-end).

But in front end I need to do one extra thing.Based on value I need to define color attribute (value < 10, color green etc..)

```
export class ModelA {
id: string;
name: string;
value: number;
color: string;
}
```

So when I'm updating ModelA back to the server after editing id/name whatever I don't want to pass color attribute.

With single model how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for in this case is slicing (see for example this : [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties) )

You are effectively taking a subset of the properties of your object,

```
let objectFront = { id: 'a', name: 'b', value: 'c', color: "d" };
let objectBack = (({id, name, value}) => ({id, name, value}))(objectFront);
```

---

EDIT:
Also, I am not sure how having more properties on your object is bad for you. It depends on your framework and your method of query.  I would just go for simply ignoring the additional properties of my object when receiving it on back-end part.

Comment: My scenario is slightly different. I'll get ModelA from server and I want to add 1 extra attribute to it. While updating back to the server I don't need to pass the extra added attribute.

Extra added attribute is only required with in front end.

Comment: Having more unnecessary property is bad because we are sending more data to back-end.

Comment: Then, I don't see how you can achieve this with a single model. You have modelA, the real data model from your server, and modelB is what I would call a ViewModel (not sure if it 's the right term here). I would make the "transtyping" in the service who is responsible for sending your object.

Comment: yea, currently I'm using 2 models. Just wondering whether we can achieve with single model or not.

Comment: What you could, but I don't know if it is applicable in your case, Is completely separate the color property from the model. Use a wrapper object that contains your `modelA ` object as first property and  'color' information as second property. When you do your request, you just send wrapper.modelA and not the whole object wrapper.

Comment: Indeed this works. I can add attributes when needed and can slice it when not required. Only thing is those extra attributes which I need in front-end must to be optional property.
color?:string;
thanks for the help!! cheers