# Object destructuring to a named object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to destructure an object using the following code.

```
const searchdata = {
    org,
    packageName,
    description,
    keywords
} = this.state;
```

but I get the following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: org is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here? could we destruture and object into another named object?

**added a sample of the state object**

```
this.state = {
    searchKey: '',
    onValueChange: false,
    org: '',
    packageName: '',
    description: '',
    keywords: '',
};
```

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Not in one step, no. You could desctructure into the separate parts *then* assign them back into an object using shorthand: `const { org, packageName, description, keywords } = this.state; const searchData = { org, packageName, description, keywords };`. Or use an immediately-invoked function to do it per the dupe I just linked.

Comment: it's not the case. When I remove the `searchdata` assignment, it works perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Comment: @ImeshChandrasiri Please, provide reproducible example. Code that you provided works fine.

Comment: Wrap in parentheses like `const searchdata = ({org, packageName...} = this.state)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can do it in a one step. He needs to wrap a right assignment into parentheses

Comment: @TheReason for me that gives you all of the content of `this.state` in `searchData`.

Comment: well I managed to do it using the following code. `const searchData = ((org, packageName, description, keywords) => (org, packageName, description, keywords))(this.state);` but is there a more cleaner way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeap you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by way of elimination using [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring):

```js
const state = {
  searchKey: '',
  onValueChange: false,
  org: '',
  packageName: '',
  description: '',
  keywords: '',
};

const {
  searchKey,
  onValueChange,
  ...searchdata
} = state;

console.log(searchdata);
```

Comment: This looks like almost perfect but isn't it unnecessary to define variables that are not needed?

Comment: This is how you omit stuff from an object using destructuring. It's a popular pattern and ESLint added an [option to allow it](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#ignorerestsiblings).