# Map array in array push

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

I have this empty array:

```
 prices: [
      {
          price:null,
          zone_id: null,
      }
 ]
```

how can i map my data to this empty array?
Example data.

```
product:[
   0:{
       brand: 'a',
       size: '11',
       price: '120',
       zone_id: '1'
   }
]
```

How can I push only the price and zone id to that empty prices array

what i have right now.

```
this.prices.push(product);
```

the value of prices array should be

```
prices:[
   {
      price: '120',
      zone_id: '1'
   }
]
```

Comment: You mean like this: `this.prices.push({price:product[0].price,zone_id:product[0].zone_id});`

Comment: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined got that error, but yes something like that

Answer (score 1):

If you have an empty array `prices`:

```
let prices = [];
```

and a data array `product` containing information about each product:

```
let product = [
   {
       brand: 'a',
       size: '11',
       price: '120',
       zone_id: '1'
   }, 
   {
       brand: 'b',
       size: '19',
       price: '200',
       zone_id: '4'
   }
];
```

**Single Product**:

You can push the first product's `price` and `zone_id` to the `prices` array like this (using [object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)):

```
prices.push((({price, zone_id}) => ({price, zone_id}))(product[0]));
```

**All Products:**
If you want to do the same thing for all of the products you can use a `forEach` loop:

```
product.forEach(p => {
    prices.push((({price, zone_id}) => ({price, zone_id}))(p));
});
```

**All Products (Replacement):**

If you want to do add all products and don't care about the original contents of the `prices` array (or if you know it will be empty) you can just use a map to apply the same function to each entry of `product` and store the result in `prices`:

```
prices = product.map(({price, zone_id}) => ({price, zone_id}));
```

Comment: hi olln I got this error: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Comment: It's likely that you haven't declared the `product` array correctly. In the original post you've written:

    `product:[
       0:{
           brand: 'a',
           size: '11',
           price: '120',
           zone_id: '1'
       }
    ]`

But that isn't valid. To store something in a variable you need to use `=` and `let`/`const`/`var`, like: 

   `let product = ...`

And you can't use "key:value" for the items in an array (no `0:...`). Try:
`let product = [
   {
      brand: 'a',
      size: '11',
      price: '120',
      zone_id: '1'
  }
]`