# Is there a quick one-liner to get properties out of an object onto a new object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Something that has the same effect as:

```
const obj = {a:'a', b:'b', c:'c'};
const {a, b} = obj;
const result = {a, b};
```

Or, in ES5:

```
const obj = {a:'a', b:'b', c:'c'};
const result = Object.keys(obj)
    .filter((key) => ['a', 'b', 'c'].includes(key))
    .reduce((acc, key) => acc[key] = obj[key], {})
```

I thought

```
const result = { a, b } = obj;
```

would work, but apparently, it just has the same effect of:

```
const result = obj;
```

in that `result` has all of the properties of obj and it also seems to 'point' to it (`result.a = 'changed'` results in `obj.a === changed` to be true). It this a bug?

Comment: I'd just use a library to pluck keys to create the new object, e.g., lodash. But if you also want a deep clone, then you need to deep clone.

Comment: ES5 (ECMA-262 ed 5) was ECMAScript 2011. Things have moved on, the most recent version is ECMA-262 ed 9 aka ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: *"It this a bug?"* No. The result of assignment is the value that was assigned. `const result = { a, b } = obj;` is the same as `const result = ({ a, b } = obj);` where `{ a, b } = obj` is a destructuring assignment, i.e. you are assigning to two local variables `a` and `b`. You are not creating a new object. In other words, your code is equivalent to `a = obj.a; b = obj.b; const result = obj;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = {...obj}
```

Would that work? It's not deep copy but neither is your first example.

Answer (score 0):

To clone an `Object` so it points to a different memory location, i.e. changes to either clone doesn't affect the other, you can use:

1- `Object.assign()`:

```
const result = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

2.- The spread operator (in ES6):

```
const result = {...obj};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can make your line

```
const result = { a, b } = obj;
```

work in the way that it seems you intend it to by, as others have said, using a deep copy of obj rather than referring to obj itself. One way to do this which may be the "quick one liner" you're looking for would be

```
const result = (({ a, b }) => ({ a, b }))(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` just gives a deep copy of `obj`. Thus changes to `result` will not affect `obj`, nor vice versa.

```js
const obj = {a:'a', b:'b', c:'c'};
const result = (({ a, b }) => ({ a, b }))(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
console.log(result);//expected output: Object { a: "a", b: "b" }

result.a = 'changed';
console.log(result);//expected output: Object { a: "changed", b: "b" }
console.log(obj);//expected output: Object { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }
```

Some performance info on this method of deep copy is shared in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/10146245), and that thread has some alternatives.

An explanation of the syntax of the object destructuring syntax can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39333479/10146245).

Comment: At first I misunderstood what you were going for. I've edited my answer to reflect what I think you're after now that I think I understand better.

Comment: *"JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) just gives a deep copy of obj."* But throws away everything that cannot be encoded as JSON.

Comment: @Felix Kling yes, perhaps most notably keys with functions as their values and date objects. (This is discussed in more depth in the SO thread that I linked in my answer which contains discussion and alternatives about deep cloning methods)