# javascript serialization with required fields

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to copy only required values to a object from JSON string.

#### JSON string

```
{  
   "name":"John",
   "age":31,
   "city":"New York",
   "place" : "Ne"
}
```

On conversion of above string the result should be

```
Object a= {"name":"John","address":"","place":"Ne"}
```

Comment: `var newObj = { "name":otherObj.name, "address":otherObj.address }`

Comment: Parse the string to object using JSON.parse and copy specific values from it. If you are open to libraries, lodash has a way `.pick` for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **Object destructuring**. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

```
const oldObj = {  
   "name":"John",
   "age":31,
   "city":"New York",
   "place" : "Ne"
}
const { name, age, city } = oldObj;
const newObj = { name, age, city };
```