# Destructure an object by an array of its keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say that we have an object like this one:

```
let obj = {a: "John", b: "Sarah", c: "Lara", d: "Joseph", e: "Roger"}
```

And an array of some of its keys:

```
let arr_of_keys = ["a", "d", "e"]
```

Is it possible to destructure the object using the predefined keys in the array, something along the lines of:

```
let {...arr_of_keys} = obj;
```

To finally end up with:

> a = "John", d = "Joseph", e = "Roger"

Comment: No, because that would mean dynamic variable names, which are quite a code smell. (also, `a` is already defined)

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `let arr_of_keys = ['a', 'd', 'e']`? What you have is an array of references to some things.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, my bad, edited, thanks for the insight, completely missed it

Comment: Closest thing I found, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a simple [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method like the one below:

```
var result = arr_of_keys.reduce(function(o,item){

    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item)){
        o[item] = obj[item]; 
    }

  return o;
}, {});
```

Here's an example:

```js
let obj = {a: "John", b: "Sarah", c: "Lara", d: "Joseph", e: "Roger"}
let arr_of_keys = ["a", "d", "e", "f"];

var result = arr_of_keys.reduce(function(o,item){

 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item)){
   o[item] = obj[item]; 
  }
  
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnfx81br/) runnable (since the built-in one returns a 503.)

Comment: it kinda doesn’t as it basically filters an object. OP said destructure which would create distinct variables.

Comment: @evolutionxbox "It kinda doesn't" isn't a valid reason. Just because the wording of a question states something it doesn't mean it's the way to go. Also you need to filter an object given you have two arrays to work with where values in one depend on the outcome - so at some point, a filter will take place regardless. In my answer there is no need for deconstructing an object.

Comment: I'm aware. I used the word "kinda" for that reason. I should have stated that I agree with your reasoning and the solution provided is better than what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible helper function for the provided issue. I added a set conversion to remove possible duplications in order save resources. Also added simple error handling in form of console error messages.

```js
const obj = {a: "John", b: "Sarah", c: "Lara", d: "Joseph", e: "Roger"}

const arr_of_keys = ["a", "d", "e"];


const customObjectDescructurer = (arrayOfDesiredPropKeys, object) => {

  const setOfDesiredPropKeys = new Set(arrayOfDesiredPropKeys);
  
  const filteredObject = [...setOfDesiredPropKeys].reduce(
    (filteredObject, desiredPropKey) => {
      if(object.hasOwnProperty(desiredPropKey)){
        filteredObject[desiredPropKey] = object[desiredPropKey];
      } else {
        console.error(`
          The given ${desiredPropKey}, does not exist in ${object} object.
        `);
      }
      return filteredObject;
    }, {});

  return filteredObject;
  
}


const desiredKeys = customObjectDescructurer(arr_of_keys, obj);

console.log(desiredKeys);
```