# destructuring js object from keys stored in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a big API answer with nested keys,
that i don't want to add to my store as is.
let's say i have an object

```
var apiResponse = {
  ... some fields
  lines: [{
  a: 'xxx',
  b: 'xxx',
  c: 'xxx',
  d: 'xxx',
  e: 'xxx'
}]
}
```

for now i am using

```
apiResponse.lines.map( ({a, b, e})  => ({a, b, e}) )
```

note there are more than 120 fields, and i may need to select more fields than i need today.
so for code simplicity (or make it cleaner) 
i am trying to have an array lineFields

```
const neededFields = ['a', 'b' , 'e']
apiResponse.lines.map( ( { 'use my neededFieldsArray' } )  => ( { 'use my neededFieldsArray' }) ;
```

so when they day comes and i need to add fields , i just add in the neededFields array .

i used this approach with ODATA API before and it works like a charm because it accepts a string

```
var odataSelect= ['userName', 'Bio', 'ProfilePic']

var customUrl = `http://apiuri:someport/users?$select=${odataSelect.join(',')}`
```

i made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hcdp1e)  template to test on.
thank you

Comment: This doesn't look like a task for destructuring at all, it's the wrong tool.

Comment: @ASDFGerte how would you do it ?

Comment: You could [reduce the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184094) OR [use `Object.fromEntries()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592365)

Comment: One way would be `neededFields.reduce((p, c) => (p[c] = original[c], p), {})`, but the dupe targets show many possibilities.

Comment: ok i will try both solutions and add an iteration to it , thanks

Comment: ```const filtered = ['id', 'name'].reduce((result, key) => { result[key] = orig[key]; return result; }, {}); ```
i ended up using this and added an iteration  , works like intended, no repetition,