# How to filter collection according to array values when compared with collection keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

Collection:

```
dict={
"ABC": 2, 
"DEF": 2, 
"GHI": 1, 
"JKL": 1, 
"MNO": 4, 
"PQR": 1}
```

When Compared with array:

```
valueArrayData=["ABC", "PQR", "STU", "JKL", "VWX", "YZA", "BCD"]
```

The output should be:

```
{
"ABC": 2,
"JKL": 1,
"PQR": 1
}
```

I have tried with lodash array methods `_.pickBy` and `_.differenceWith`:

```
var array = _.pickBy(dict, function(value, key) {
  return _.differenceWith(key, valueArrayData, _.isEqual);
});
console.log(array);
```

But seems like it is not working.

Comment: You can just use `_.pick()` like so: `_.pick(dict, valueArrayData)`

Comment: You want the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17781649/5648954) from the link above

Comment: @NickParsons 
_.pick(dict, valueArrayData) is giving me empty object: `{}`.
the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties/17781649#17781649
--> Gives output as same array dict.

Comment: See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9srhyL5g/) with _your_ data, if it is giving you an empty object then something else must be causing it

Comment: It seems like https://jsfiddle.net/9srhyL5g/ is working, need to check the data format of array objects.
Thanks!