# javascript destructure object to 'this'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object-destructuring

I would like to assign pagination result from response.data to Vue data
so the obvious way is simply

```
    this.data = response.data.data
    this.total = response.data.total
    this.perPage = response.data.per_page
```

But is there an ES6 way to assign the result directly to something like this?

```
    const page = { data, total, per_page : perPage } = response.data
    this = { ...this, ...page }
```

Note: the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with `this` - `this` can't be reassigned.

If the `data` object contains *only* those properties, and you changed the `per_page` property of the `response.data` to `perPage`, then you could use `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign(this, response.data);
```

If the `data` object contains other properties, or you can't rename `per_page`, then:

```
const { data, total, per_page : perPage } = response.data
Object.assign(this, { data, total, perPage });
```

Comment: Object.assign is nice, is there anyway we can do this with spread operator? just to make sure.

Comment: Only if you had one or two properties of `.data` to *exclude*. Otherwise, it wouldn't accomplish anything that `Object.assign` doesn't take care of already.

Comment: tried that, still got "ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable data"

Comment: I did have "const page = ..." and then "Object.assign(this, page)", is there anywhere else?

Comment: Have to remove the `page =` part, otherwise `= { data, total, per_page : perPage } =` will try to assign to already existing variables named `data`, `total`, `perPage`. Destructure into standalone variables instead, then put those together into an object when passing to `Object.assign`

Comment: Yes, thank you, from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties. Turned out it's pretty complex thing to do.

Comment: I understand now why you have to make another object in the assign function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So from @CertainPerformance's answer and looking into how to retrieve subset properties of an object from [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

I got a working solution with object destructuring.

```
    const page = (({ data, total, per_page: perPage }) => ({ data, total, perPage }))(response.data)
    Object.assign(this, page)
```

However the code is not shortened or easier to read, so I go back to the obvious way.