# How to creates an object with only the listed keys?

Tags: javascript

Creates an object composed of the picked source properties.

Parameters

- `source` - Any JavaScript Object
- `keys` - An array of JavaScript Strings

Return Value

A new Object containing all of the properties of source listed in keys. If a key is listed in keys, but is not defined in source, then that property is not added to the new Object.

Examples

```
pick({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, ['foo', 'baz']) // -> { foo: 1, baz: 3 }
pick({ qux: 4, corge: 5 }, ['bar', 'grault'])    // -> {}
pick({ bar: 2 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])          // -> { bar: 2 }
```

I have

```
function pick(source, keys) {
  let result = {};
  for (key in source) {
    if (key === keys) {
      result[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

so far

Comment: What are you expecting the statement `result[key];` to do? When is a `key` (a string) going to be exactly equal to `keys` (an array)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 5):

You're not assigning anything to `result[key]`, that should be `result[key] = source[key]`.

You're not testing whether `key` is in `keys` correctly. `===` does exact comparison, you want to use `keys.includes(key)` to test inclusion.

```js
function pick(source, keys) {
  let result = {};
  for (key in source) {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      result[key] = source[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(pick({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, ['foo', 'baz'])) // -> { foo: 1, baz: 3 }
console.log(pick({ qux: 4, corge: 5 }, ['bar', 'grault']))    // -> {}
console.log(pick({ bar: 2 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))          // -> { bar: 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Object.entries to iterate through the values and keys

```js
function pick(object,arr){
  o={}
      Object.entries(object).forEach(x=>{
        if(arr.includes(x[0]))   o[x[0]]=x[1]
      })
      return o
}
console.log(pick({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, ['foo', 'baz'])) // -> { foo: 1, baz: 3 }
console.log(pick({ qux: 4, corge: 5 }, ['bar', 'grault']) )   // -> {}
console.log(pick({ bar: 2 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))        // -> { bar: 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if each key exists in your object then add it to the new object and finally return it.

```js
function pick(src, keys) {
  var newObj = {};
  keys.forEach(key => key in src && (newObj[key] = src[key]));
  return newObj;
}

console.log(pick({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, ['foo', 'baz']));
console.log(pick({ qux: 4, corge: 5 }, ['bar', 'grault']));
console.log(pick({ bar: 2 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating through all the object keys (not all of which may be of interest), it would be more efficient to iterate through the array of desired keys. Also, since *testing* whether an object has a key and *getting* the key's value would require repeating some of the same internal operations, it may be faster to just attempt to get the value and test for `undefined`.

```js
function pick(obj, keys) {
  var res = {};
  for (k of keys) {
    var v = obj[k];
    if (v != undefined)
      res[k] = v;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(pick({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }, ['foo', 'baz'])) // -> { foo: 1, baz: 3 }
console.log(pick({ qux: 4, corge: 5 }, ['bar', 'grault']))    // -> {}
console.log(pick({ bar: 2 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']))          // -> { bar: 2 }
```