# The device.servicesUUIDs out the then.catch print but inside the value

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using the library react-native-ble-plx to connect Bluetooth to my application, but I need some values, when I log console.log(device) returns me any values, and I found the servicesUUIDs, it is an array an the position zero, contains the id about the module chip I am using, but when I print inside the then().catch(), does not log the value that I need, but the out the then().catch(), print the ID.

Comment: can you show us the exact code and where it is not printing what you expect? If possible, with the example data so we know the shape

Comment: @Gonzalo.- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63799393/the-device-servicesuuids-out-the-then-catch-print-but-inside-the-value-is-null