# How can i add fields inside empty array?

Tags: javascript

Good morning guys

I have to create a new JSON object array using the user array but when I do this getting the below error.
could someone help me here? or help me to understand the mistake?

```js
var users = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"fiat" },{ "name":"Raj", "age":28, "car":"hundai" }];

var allUser =[]

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  test(i, users[i])
}
console.log(allUser)

function test(i, user) {
  console.log(i)
  <!-- allUser.push({"username":user.name}); -->

  allUser[i].username = user.name;
  //allUser[i].userage = user.age;
  //allUser[i].usercar = user.car;
}
```

[image]

Expected Result:

all user should be like this

```
[{ "username":"John", "userage":30 },{ "username":"Raj", "userage":28 }]
```

Comment: `allUser` has a *single* item. Getting `allUser[i]` is using the indexes from `users`, so with `i = 1`, `allUser[1]` produces `undefined`.

Comment: how can I get all users like this [{ "username":"John", "userage":30 },{ "username":"Raj", "userage":28 }]

Comment: Option 1 - remove `<!-- -->` Option 2 [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19590865) + [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781472)

Comment: what is the problem with option 2? any idea?

Comment: There is no problem. Either uncomment the line that will add items to `allUsers` or use `.map`. I've pointed you to two resources for how to use `.map` to get a subsection of the keys of an object.

Comment: Please find my answer .i have just edited your code.map should have been a better option.But I have edited your code to get output.

Comment: @itsme also solved the problem with map function.Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test` function can be fixed in the following manner:

```js
var users = [
  { "name": "John", "age": 30, "car": "fiat"   },
  { "name": "Raj",  "age": 28, "car": "hundai" },
];

var allUser = [];

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  test(i, users[i]);
}
console.log(allUser);

function test(i, user) {
  allUser[i] = {}; // create and assign a new object to `allUser[i]`
  allUser[i].username = user.name;
  allUser[i].userage = user.age;
  allUser[i].usercar = user.car;
}
```

However the above looks over complicated, and a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call would simplify things a lot.

```js
var users = [
  { "name": "John", "age": 30, "car": "fiat"   },
  { "name": "Raj",  "age": 28, "car": "hundai" },
];

var allUser = users.map((user) => ({
  username: user.name,
  userage: user.age,
  usercar: user.car,
}));

console.log(allUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the fiddle for solution. https://jsfiddle.net/gczwk2jf/
Your alluser array is empty array, when you try to get value by a[i] e.g. a[0] or a[1], it is undefined. You are trying to access username of undefined value hence you have an error.
Best way is to map or compose your complete object and assign it your array index.

```
allUser[i] = {
username: user.name,
userage: user.age
}
```

With map, you can replace the entire code with following couple of lines

```
var users = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"fiat" },{ "name":"Raj", "age":28, "car":"hundai" }];
var allUser = users.map(user => return {
username: user.name,
userage: user.age
});
```

Map is a higher order function that doesn't mutate your original array, which means you get a new array after map, keeping original user array unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var users = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"fiat" },{ "name":"Raj", "age":28, "car":"hundai" }];

var allUser =[]

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  test(i, users[i])
}
console.log(allUser)

function test(i, user) {
var data={}

  data["username"]=user["name"];
  data["userage"]=user["age"]
  allUser.push(data);

}
```

using `map` function

```js
var users = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"fiat" },{ "name":"Raj", "age":28, "car":"hundai" }];

var allUser =[]

users.map((element)=>{
test(element)
})
console.log(allUser)

function test(user) {
var data={}

  data["username"]=user["name"];
  data["userage"]=user["age"]
  allUser.push(data);

}
```

Please try this.