# Map specific properties from an array into a new array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of employees. I want to create a new array `employeeNames` that has only the firstName and lastName properties. I believe I can do this with the `map()` method but I'm not exactly sure how.

```
let employees = { firstName: 'Collin', lastName: 'Sexton', email: 'exampe@test.com', dob: '03/20/1986' ... }
```

Resulting array should look like:

```
employeeNames = { firstName: 'Collin', lastName: 'Sexton' }
```

Comment: But what you have shared is an object? Can you clarify your question

Comment: In case, you have valid array, then you need something like this `employees.map(({firstName, lastName}) => ({firstName, lastName}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you meant you have array of objects. So you'd do:

```
const projected = empArray.map((empItem) => ({
    firstName: empItem.firstName,
    lastName: empItem.lastName,
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for array as a result though.. do this

```
let { firstName, lastName } = employees;
let employeeNames = { firstName, lastName };
```

What we do here is called deconstruction. We bind the values of 'firstName' and 'lastName' to variables with the same name and then create a new Object with those variables. If no keys are given, it automagically names them after the variables.

Answer (score 0):

employees is an object which is not iterable, so you need to convert before being able to `map()` a new one.

Which can easity be made with `Object.entries()`

so..

```
// key is the object key while value is the object value of corresponding key
let newArray = Object.entries(employees).map((key, value) => {
   let arrayEntry;
   if (key === 'firstName' || key === 'lastName') {
      newEntry = value;
   }
   return arrayEntry;
});
```

Your new array should then output to `[John, Doe, Jane, Doe, name, lastname]`

Answer (score -1):

Here is how it will be if you need to map array of eployees to array with only needed props:

```
let employees = [{ firstName: 'Collin', lastName: 'Sexton', email: 'exampe@test.com', dob: '03/20/1986'}]
let result = employees.map({firstName, lastName}=> ({ firstName, lastName}));
```

Comment: Code-only answers generally do not fare well on Stack Overflow, some explanation is beneficial. See [answer].