# Subset of columns of JSON Data in TypeScript React project

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a typescript project wherein I get data of the form :

```
const data1 =  { id: 0, rac: 43, tcreated: "12-04-21", tupdated: "12-09-22", Custname: "A" }
```

Now I want to filter the columns for further processing dynamically,

```
const fields = ["id", "tcreated", "Custname"];
```

I found the solution for normal Javascript as

```
const subset = fields.reduce((a, e) => ((a[e] = data1[e]), a), {});
```

But the same doesn't work in my typescript React project. I tried various other ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties) but none seem to work on account of type mismatch TS7053.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try this way - https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-sound-4f9zo?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an `interface` like below,

```
 interface DataConfig {
    [propName: string]: string | number;
  }

  const data1: DataConfig = {
    id: 0,
    rac: 43,
    tcreated: "12-04-21",
    tupdated: "12-09-22",
    Custname: "A"
  };
```

And mention the element type in the iteration,

```
 const subset = fields.reduce(
    (a: DataConfig, e) => ((a[e] = data1[e]), a),
    {}
  );
```