# How to declare subset enum from another enum

Tags: typescript

Then there is the code:

```js
enum all {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
  c = 'c',
}


// what I want enum
enum wanted {
  c = 'c',
}
```

I know there are some solutions like

```js
type wanted = Exclude<all, all.a | all.b> // type wanted = all.c
```

But type is different from enum, as it's not iterable!

Comment: Some ideas for how to handle this here: https://devimalplanet.com/typescript-how-to-extend-one-enum-from-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enum is simply [an object at runtime](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime). For example, your enum `all` gets transformed to this:

```js
var all;
(function (all) {
    all["a"] = "a";
    all["b"] = "b";
    all["c"] = "c";
})(all || (all = {}));

// Essentially equivalent to
const all = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
```

You can therefore use `all` like any normal JavaScript object. There are many different ways to [pick/omit certain properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781472/8289918):

```ts
// ES2015 Destructuring
const {a, b, ...wanted} = all

// ES2019 Object.fromEntries
const wanted = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(all)
    .filter(([key]) =>
      key === 'c'
      // or if you wanted to exclude instead
      // !['a', 'b'].includes(key)
    )
) as {c: 'c'}
```

If you wanted to make the last example more type-safe, you could use this helper:

```ts
const pick = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  keys: readonly K[]
): Pick<T, K> =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) =>
      (keys as readonly string[]).includes(key)
    )
  ) as Pick<T, K>

const wanted = pick(all, ['c'])
```

Or maybe this for omitting properties instead:

```ts
const omit = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  keys: readonly K[]
): Omit<T, K> =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) =>
      !(keys as readonly string[]).includes(key)
    )
  ) as Omit<T, K>

const wanted = omit(all, ['a', 'b'])
```

In TypeScript, types can have the same names as values, so if you wanted `wanted` to also be a type (just like if you had written out the enum), you could define a type `wanted` with `Exclude` or `Pick` (like in your example).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=31&ssc=38&pln=21&pc=1#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-AFApYlSEraPQmwqtVixFk9RoyTSGQAZnIlJ4+IQhLwhAoJLByO47DgwGEcHYnnzcEE6Izcib6axbYxWbBQA)

Comment: Got it, though it seems not the perfect solution, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

I actually find a solution to merge enum

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 'Humans',
  Bats = 'Bats',
  Dolphins = 'Dolphins'
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards'
}

export const Animals = { ...Mammals, ...Reptiles };
export type Animals = typeof Animals;
```

So you can import Animals act as enum.