# How to change a function based on unknown number of arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, first-class-functions

Is there any way to add to or manipulate expressions in a returned function?

This is an example for a single argument:

```
function trackByProp(prop) {
  return function (value) {
    return value[prop];
  };
}
```

The aim is to extend this function to allow multiple props to be added e.g.

```
function trackByProp(...props) {
  props.forEach((prop) => {
    //Somehow add value[prop] to the return function???
  });

  return function (value) {
    return; // value[arg1] + value[arg2] + value[argN]
  };
}
```

Alternatively is there a simpler way to create this function ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17781472) then do whatever you want with them?

Comment: @Andreas How would I use reduce() in this situation? 
It's not possible to just accumulate the value[props] as value isn't know at the time of calling ? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @NicholasFoden "*It's not possible to just accumulate the value[props] as value isn't know at the time of calling*" why do you even want to do that *before* the inner function is called? If the code is in the inner function, then you do have `value`.

Comment: What I haven't been able to work out is how to get the multiple lookups into the inner function.

Comment: `return props.reduce((prop, result) => result + value[prop])` or what ever your `value[arg1] + value[arg2] ...` actually is supposed to be.

Comment: thanks @VLAZ your link shows lodash's pick seems to be what I am looking for. I am still interested in learning how I would do it myself. perhaps I will just read the lodash code.

Comment: "*how to get the multiple lookups into the inner function.*" with loop or other iteration?

Answer (score 0):

```
function trackByProps(...props) {
  return function (value) {
    return props.reduce((result, prop) => result + value[prop], "")
  }
}
```

Using the properties in the inner function ensures they are available in a closure. similar to the single argument example. Then they can be iterated over each time the inner function is called.

Comment: In FP we try to keep functions as simple as possible. Your original function is just fine. If you want to process several properties just `map` over them.