# How can I pass query parameters optional using axios in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuex

I try like this :

```
const actions = {
    getData ({ commit }, payload) {
      const params = {}
      if(payload) {
        if (payload.dateFrom) { params.date_from = payload.dateFrom }
        if (payload.dateTo) { params.date_to = payload.dateTo}
      }
      axios
        .get(`${api}/reports/list`, {params})
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
    }
}
```

If I console.log(payload), the result like this :

{from: '2022-07-01', to: '2022-07-30'}

payload is optional

My code is working. But I want to know if there is a *more concise way to express it*.

Comment: Looking for a _"better way"_ is inviting opinion which makes this off-topic for StackOverflow. If what you've got works, there isn't a problem to solve here

Comment: It's unknown what's the definition of a better way in this case. undefined params are omitted, but it's unknown what are possible values of `from` and `to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditional add property to object like this:

```js
const actions = {
  getData({ commit }, payload) {
    const params = {
      ...(payload?.dateFrom && {
        date_from: payload.dateFrom
      }),
      ...(payload?.dateTo && {
        date_to: payload.dateTo
      })
    };
    axios
      .get(`${api}/reports/list`, { params })
      .then((r) => r.data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: TIL that spreading `undefined` results in an empty object. You might want to use some optional chaining in case `payload` itself is `undefined`... `payload?.dateFrom`

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to default the param, then conditionally add its props, like...

```
getData ({ commit }, payload={}) {
  const params = {
    ...(payload.from ? {from: payload.from}: {}),
    ...(payload.to ? {to: payload.to}: {}),
  }
  axios
    .get(`${api}/reports/list`, {params})  // etc
```

That's still a little bit clumsy conditional inclusion of key-value pairs. Another idea, since it's really a kind of pick, you could code that explicitly (and reuse it elsewhere)...

```
// pick, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592365/294949
function pick(obj={}, keys=[])
  return Object.fromEntries(
    keys.filter(key => key in obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]])
  );
}
```

Then `getData` is...

```
getData ({ commit }, payload) {
  const params = pick(payload, ['from', 'to']);
  axios
    .get(`${api}/reports/list`, {params})  // etc
```

**edit** if the key names will change, then it's not a pick. The first idea still works, and given the switch is probably close to minimal code...

```
getData ({ commit }, payload={}) {
  const params = {
    ...(payload.dateFrom ? {date_from: payload.dateFrom}: {}),
    ...(payload.dateTo ? {date_to: payload.dateTo}: {}),
  }
  axios
    .get(`${api}/reports/list`, {params})  // etc
```

Comment: @positivedeveloper, since the key names are different, the "pick" idea is no longer useful, but the first one still works.  See the edit, at the bottom, where the new key names are accounted for.  (I left the original answer in case future readers have a question like the original)

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```js
  getTest({ commit }, { from = undefined, to = undefined }) {
    axios
      .get(`api/reports/list`, { params: { from, to } })
      .then((r) => r.data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

so when you want to use the action
you can do these

this.$store.dispatch("getTest", { from: 121 });

this.$store.dispatch("getTest",{});
//at least an empty Object

Comment: axios needs an object with a 'params' key.  And if payload is nullish, { undefined, undefined }, is probably a runtime error.

Comment: @Caffeine Cat There exist error `Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: sorry my fault.I find another way.

Comment: @danh sorry,i forget the {params:params} = {params},i changed the answer.In the new answer,if the 'from' or 'to' is undifined,it wont be carried into the request.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
const actions = {
    getData ({ commit }, payload) {
      const params = { ...payload }
      axios
        .get(`${api}/reports/list`, { params })
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
    }
}
```