# Assigning an object to type interface but removing properties not included in the interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with additional properties but only want to return certain properties defined by an interface to the backend.

Is there a clean solution to this? I have checked online and a lot seem to refer to the Omit, Pick etc. utility methods. However, I have tried that but it returns all the properties of the object and does not omit/pick the required properties.

```
interface Student{
name: string;
age: number;
address: string;
}
```

an example object:

```
{name: "John Doe", age: 30, address: "123 ...", phoneNumber: "xxxxx", nextOfKin: "Marie Doe", ....}
```

I have tried:

```
type StudentInfoRequest = Omit<Student, "phoneNumber" | "nextOfKin">
type StudentInfoRequest = Pick<Student, "name" | "age" | "address">
```

when I assign it e.g.

```
let studentRequestList: StudentInfoRequest[] = [];
```

looping over the student objects to push into the `studentRequestList` and when I console log it includes the entire properties of the object rather than the interface only properties.

Comment: If you have tried something, then why not present the code of what you tried? Ideally a [mre].

Comment: @JoachimSauer I have added part of my code into the description

Comment: Types don't affect the runtime behaviour of your program. You will have to use JavaScript to remove these properties.

Comment: @TobiasS. That is interesting to know especially since types is mentioned quite a lot as a solution unless I have misunderstood it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)