# javascript assign variable to key-values extracted from object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, object-destructuring

how can i do something like the following

```
const BigObject = {
"id":"value",
"img":"value",
"name":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",

}
var User = {id,img,name} = BigObject
```

where User will be an object like

```
{
    "id":"value",
    "img":"value",
    "name":"value",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Comment: An approach like ... `const user = (({ id, img, name }) => ({ id, img, name }))(BigObject);` ... which is based on an immediately invoked arrow function prevents additional local references which are not needed anymore after the creation of `user`.

Answer (score 2):

From my above comment ...

> *"An approach like ... `const user = (({ id, img, name }) => ({ id, img, name }))(BigObject);` ... which is based on an immediately invoked arrow function prevents additional local references which are not needed anymore after the creation of `user`."*

Implementing the solution with an arrow function might also come closest to the OP'S original intention ...

```js
const bigObject = {
  id: 'value',
  img: 'value',
  name: 'value',
  otherData: 'value',
};

// OP ...how can i do something like the following?..
//
// const user = { id, img, name } = bigObject

// prevent additional module or global
// scope of e.g. `id`, `img`, `name`.
const user = (({ id, img, name }) => ({ id, img, name }))(bigObject);

console.log({ user });
```

Comment: This is awesome exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```js
const {id, img, name} = BigObject;
const User = {id, img, name};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like below:

```js
const BigObject = {
 "id":"value",
 "img":"value",
 "name":"value",
 "otherData":"value",
 "otherData":"value",
 "otherData":"value",
 "otherData":"value"
}
let {id, img, name, ...rest} = BigObject;
let User = {id,img,name};
console.log(User)
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can do something like this

```
const BigObject = {
"id":"value",
"img":"value",
"name":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",
"otherData":"value",

}
let {id,img,name} = BigObject
const User = {id,img,name}
console.log(User)
```