# How can I filter certain items out of an array of objects using values from a different array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

For example, if I begin with this array in JavaScript:

```
Array Persons:
[0]: { Name: Henry, Age: 20, Height: 68, Weight: 150}
[1]: { Name: Tom, Age: 34, Height: 69, Weight: 140}
[2]: { Name: Jerry, Age: 45 Height: 63, Weight: 175}
```

and then I have the array of the fields I want to pull

```
Array Filter:
[0]: "Name"
[1]: "Weight"
```

How can I filter the first array using the second to then return only those fields stated in the second array?

Expected return:

```
Array Persons2:
[0]: { Name: Henry, Weight: 150}
[1]: { Name: Tom, Weight: 140}
[2]: { Name: Jerry, Weight: 175}
```

Thanks! Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Could you please provide the arrays as actual valid code?

Comment: From the duplicate, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592365/283366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods as follows:

```js
const persons = [{ Name: "Henry", Age: 20, Height: 68, Weight: 150},{ Name: "Tom", Age: 34, Height: 69, Weight: 140},{ Name: "Jerry", Age: 45, Height: 63, Weight: 175}],

filter = ["Name","Weight"],

persons2 = persons.map(
  person => filter.reduce(
    (acc, prop) => ({...acc, [prop]: person[prop]}),
  {})
);

console.log( persons2 );
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was trying to get to