# How to get only particular object property with values from an json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get some particular property with value from an array object.But it is not working.How to resolve this issue?

```
var arr1 = [
  {
   name: 'john',
   team: [12, 23, 34],
   sid: 1023,
   options:{boolean:true}
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 233, 354],
    sid: 1024,
    options:{boolean:true}
   },
  {
   name: 'john',
   team: [152, 273, 314],
   sid: 1025,
   options:{boolean:true}
  },
  ];


 const filteredResult = arr1.find((e) => e.!sid && e.!options);

 console.log(filteredResult);
```

filteredResult should be like

```
[
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [12, 23, 34]
    
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 233, 354]
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 273, 314]
  }
];
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-73yhgm?file=index.js

Comment: `arr1.map({name, team} => ({ name, team }))`

Comment: @0stone0: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7ytzjc?file=index.js

Comment: @EMahanK It should be `arr1.map(({name, team}) => ({name, team}))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.map()` should do it. Just return the specific properties that you want

```js
var arr1 = [{
    name: 'john',
    team: [12, 23, 34],
    sid: 1023,
    options: {
      boolean: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 233, 354],
    sid: 1024,
    options: {
      boolean: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 273, 314],
    sid: 1025,
    options: {
      boolean: true
    }
  },
];

const result = arr1.map(x => ({
  name: x.name,
  team: x.team
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure only the properties you want to be returned.

```js
const arr1=[{name:"john",team:[12,23,34],sid:1023,options:{boolean:!0}},{name:"john",team:[152,233,354],sid:1024,options:{boolean:!0}},{name:"john",team:[152,273,314],sid:1025,options:{boolean:!0}},];
const res = arr1.map(({name, team}) => ({name, team}));
console.log(res);
```

Or, with a dynamic array of properties to extract:

```js
const arr1=[{name:"john",team:[12,23,34],sid:1023,options:{boolean:!0}},{name:"john",team:[152,233,354],sid:1024,options:{boolean:!0}},{name:"john",team:[152,273,314],sid:1025,options:{boolean:!0}},];
const keys = ['name', 'team'];
const res = arr1.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr1.find()` will only [return the first matching element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=de). Use array `filter` instead if you want to get all the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function that will filter down to the property set you want to return.  Then use the map function on the array and pass in the custom function (selectFewerProps) just defined.

```js
var arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [12, 23, 34],
    sid: 1023,
    options:{boolean:true}
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 233, 354],
    sid: 1024,
    options:{boolean:true}
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    team: [152, 273, 314],
    sid: 1025,
    options:{boolean:true}
  },
];

function selectFewerProps(show){
  const {name, team} = show;
  return {name, team};
}

const filteredResult = arr1.map(selectFewerProps);

console.log(filteredResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use array.forEach() like that :

```js
    let result = [];

    var arr1 = [
      {
        name: 'john',
        team: [12, 23, 34],
        sid: 1023,
        options: {
            boolean: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'john',
        team: [152, 233, 354],
        sid: 1024,
        options: {
            boolean: true
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'john',
        team: [152, 273, 314],
        sid: 1025,
        options: {
            boolean: true
        }
      },
    ];

    arr1.forEach(obj => {
        result.push({
            name: obj.name,
            team: obj.team
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```