# How to set the key type and value type during object asign in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
interface Student {
  id: number
  name: string
  age: number
}
let alice: Student = { name: "alice",  age: 19, id: 1 }
const bob: Student = { name: "Bob", age: 19, id: 2 }

const keys: (keyof Student)[] = ["age", "name"]
for (let c of keys) {
  alice[c] = bob[c]  // here shows the error during compile
  /*
  src/index.ts:11:3 - error TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  */
}
```

How to edit the code so that not typscript error will occur during `alice[c] = bob[c]`?

Comment: ① Please [edit] this to explicitly ask a question inside the body of your post. Right now this is just a code block. See the "Introduce the problem before you post any code" section of [ask] ② You want [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693); until and unless that is implemented, you need to refactor to use generics, such as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NroX3m) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (once you edit your post to fix the question as per my first comment); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for your advise. The playground link's code is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently when you write code of the form `alice[c] = bob[c]`, the compiler only analyzes the *types* of the keys and not their *identities*. That means it can't tell the difference between `alice[c] = bob[c]` and `alice[c1] = bob[c2]` where `c1` and `c2` are both the same type as `c`.  One might think this is fine and that both sides of the assignment are of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `Student[keyof Student]`.

But TypeScript treats indexed access *writes* differently when the key is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `keyof Student`. This safety feature was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), and it does catch legitimate problems, since `alice[c1] = alice[c2]` really *isn't* safe; what if `c1` is `"id"` but `c2` is `"name"`, for example?

But it also prohibits some perfectly safe code.  For `alice[c] = bob[c]` we know that the `c` on each side isn't just of the same *type*, it's the *identical value*.  There's a feature request to support this sort some "same-key" assignment at [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693), but it hasn't been implemented yet.

---

Until and unless it is implemented, you'll need to refactor to a version where the compiler sees the two sides of the assignment as identical or compatible.  According to [a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) you can get this if `k` is of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.

Therefore the easiest approach here is to put the assignment inside a generic function... and the easiest way to do *that* is probably to change from a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to [the `forEach()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which takes a callback:

```
keys.forEach(<K extends keyof Student>(c: K) => {
  alice[c] = bob[c]
});
```

Now `c` is of generic type `K`, and both sides of the assignment are seen as the generic indexed access type `Student[K]`, which is allowed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwFgAoZZYLALmRAwFsAjaEskOOiagZzClAHMWyOP0416TKCQC+JADYQwwucCTV02XEoC8BGuzEAiOCqSGANMNHUAjAE5LFW8lnEEAexA9kDdw3WYOHi6+Poc1IYAQn4WVmL2jlTIAEwuJCQeXkoA1hAAnlzUABS5ee4waIFaAJQA2gC6yLq1xqKxhmwchvUkpVwAdDDuUACiiAAWRQA8ANLIEAAekCBYXMil5ZWa4AB8RQjUM9VNOwRCJqoQtQiNur4M1z3E0tUA3CRAA)

Answer (score 2):

`c` in the `for` loop has type `keyof Student`, i.e. can be any key of `Student`, whence the type of both `alice[c]` and `bob[c]` is *the union of all property types* in `Student`, namely, `string | number`.

And the problem is that, when you try to do the assignment `alice[c] = bob[c]`, TS is not smart enough to know that `alice[c]` and `bob[c]` must be of the same type: TS just knows `string | number`, which is then the type of the RHS, but on the LHS that becomes (is equivalent to) `string & number` (the union becomes an intersection!), which in turn simplifies to `never`.  Whence the error.

Here is code that works, not necessarily good for you depending on how "generic" you actually need to be, but it is illustrative of the fact that, if all properties had the same type, the assignment would work just fine, so, type guards such that in each conditional branch there is a known unique property type are sufficient to do the trick:

```
interface Student {
    id: number
    name: string
    age: number
}

let alice: Student = { name: "alice", age: 19, id: 1 };
const bob: Student = { name: "Bob", age: 19, id: 2 };

declare const keys: (keyof Student)[];
// to show that results do not depend on the specific value of `keys`

for (const c of keys) {
    if (c === "name") {
        c;  // const c: "name"

        alice[c] = bob[c];  // no error
    }
    else {
        c;  // const c: "id" | "age"

        alice[c] = bob[c];  // no error
    }

    c;  // const c: keyof Student
    const a_ = alice[c];  // const a_: string | number
    const b_ = bob[c];    // const b_: string | number

    alice[c] = bob[c];  // ERROR
    // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
}

type TEST = string & number;  // type TEST = never
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwChkTlgsAuZEDAWwCNpjSQ5aIqBnMKUAc2Yk4fDtTqMohAL6FCAGwhhkcOcCRV02XEoC8Bam1EAiFWohGANMpFUAjAE4r5O8ikBuQggD2Ibsnpe9BqYOHh6%20AbsVEYAQoGW1qIOTpTIAEyuHoQ4CHJwUCjevkoA1hAAnpxUABRl5V4waCHaAJQA2gC6HgD03chgXsicABZeAO79w3BKBZwYcmCcyFiDIF5KOAAOuFjIPpMonNsIwDBqyABuKhgoDcgABnWc97IwXlDI1UV%20CHuNTy0CIIyI0vsgdBDkEZWOwjICiKREcgEG4SL1kT4ftEYeZZEjSKYkG0EB1wf5AsSumi%20mtkNAoO9gTJERA5JwUAj8cjUch0d8lAhouQjMgAD5Q4S44GIwkQSlkgL0Sk89G0%20mMxEyYEo6kY4rIqh1O6aUJgbWYpRwAD6ZNlyt1-OUVq4PH4YrEDCYiMd9BtekV9tIfIt-mdQ1dID47ponskwLtJIVFJJKr6AFEAEoZgDyGeB6IAKuVtsgAOTcXiR6PiaClshLNaWzicYB8Vj0BT9QZgYsoUsgCAXWsAOmksh7JYLadQBbJFbdADIPRJU-1e8gpzOyQOh5IgA)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest adaption to help TypeScript detect that the [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `k` (`keyof Student`) targets the same property of `Student` is by adding a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) which infers the exact `keyof Student`.

Don't get confused by the syntax. It's just an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which wraps the assignment.

```
interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const alice: Student = { name: "alice", age: 19, id: 1 };
const bob: Student = { name: "Bob", age: 19, id: 2 };

const keys: (keyof Student)[] = ["age", "name"];

for (let k of keys) {
  (<K extends keyof Student>(k: K) => {
    alice[k] = bob[k];
  })(k);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLmQbwChllgsAuZEDAWwCNoBuYquGiSgZzClAHNmJOHw5VaDKMwC+hQggD2IbsjgAbYEkrpsuMMgC8BVu0oAiNRoimANCpGUAjAE5bZR8inMFSvXXl0tTBw8Q3xjUVMAIX8bO1FnVwpkACYPZjlFZQBrCABPTkoAChzc+Rg0IN0ASgBtAF0DZBrzEVjTEDYrOvSYeShkQtUIPSzkMuQSziqCFkKAHgBpZAgAD0gQLE4JvPHtYLAAPmLKBen9A5mSIXUkGqyGwz86O+6WKSriqulCIA)

Answer (score 1):

If you can create an object with only the desired keys from `bob`, you can simply use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy them to `alice`. How to create a correctly-typed object with only a subset of keys is answered in this question: [How to get a subset of a javascript object's properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781472/how-to-get-a-subset-of-a-javascript-objects-properties)

I simplified the implementation of `pick()` from that question a bit, to get the following simple and clean solution:

```
const pick = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]) => 
  Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, obj[key]])) as Pick<T, K>;

interface Student {
    id: number
    name: string
    age: number
}

let alice: Student = { name: "alice", age: 19, id: 1 };
const bob: Student = { name: "Bob", age: 19, id: 2 };

const keys: (keyof Student)[] = ["age", "name"];

Object.assign(alice, pick(bob, ...keys));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgS2AaxgXhgHgCowKYAeUeYAJhDAN4C+ANDANL5EnkzJ4CeIAZjNgD4AFCABGAKwBc-egDp5HThGkMA2gF0AlOgEwAUDBgB5CXmBRZPAE4gAtgFEwUKwjwQhiiLNsBDOB64dGFVFejFxEK51LW0fCgAFJGQcegYBAG49PQQnPCseH2A8GABlKABXUhJYSgNDGARSaTBy21E8usMwH1s8aWgXMABzTpgfIb6YFraO6iyAGzxYH3mkSbLK6vQqKZ7JgCIVtf36ccmARgBOekbpc5hqTNBIWFExaQ2qp23KXd7pfYAITEJzGEzu1waTRgACYHpk9M9oOwuMoYAFuHxPtVNBptqpDhNQftur19uoEQB6Sn8AAWxUKFRWMAgIHm5SgCHAAEI9CZxGYLHEIAghmAhEcivRECghG9RHIFKjNJpMkA)